# Designing efficient UDP server to handle multiple clients

Tags: sockets, server, udp

In TCP server, whenever there is a new client request, a new socket is created which handle all the send/recv for the new client. This is efficient even if there are 1000 clients.

However, in UDP server, there is only 1 socket for all the clients. Sending data to 1000s of clients with just 1 egress buffer reduces the performance. How do we design an efficient UDP server for the same scenario?

Comment: Reduces the performance how? Examine your assumptions.

Comment: Assuming the UDP server has to send 100mb of a file to multiple clients, the rate at which the clients will receive the entire data will be very less, as there is only 1 buffer in server sending data to all clients.

Comment: And the same amount of outbound network capacity in either case, which is much more to the point.

Comment: what sort of performance are you talking about?  saturating a 1Gb network port should be relatively easy for a single thread, but having any time to actually do much processing of data moving around at that rate is much more difficult.  that said have you seen the `SO_REUSEPORT` socket option?

Comment: Performance in terms of the number of bytes/sec the clients would receive would be less, as there is only one outbound buffer from the server for all the clients. However, in TCP, there is a dedicated buffer for each client and bytes/sec client receives would be high.